# Submit button not working in Ruby/Firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, firefox, erb

I'd like to have a single form that has 2 or more field-set_tags and I'd like to have a single submit button to update the changes for all field_set_tags at once, but that's not working ; if I create a form for each field_set_tag and one submit button per form, it works fine ; anyone can help? my simplified partial view _form.html.erb has the following structure

```
<%= form_for(@my_form) do |f| %>

<%= field_set_tag "Field Set A" do %>
    <div class="field>

        <%= f.label :"Configure A" %>
        <%= f.check_box :ConfigA %>
        <%= f.label :"Login" %>
        <%= f.text_field :A_Login, {:size => 12} %>
        <%= f.label :"Password" %>
        <%= f.password_field :A_Password, {:size => 12} %>

        <!-- more Ruby code here -->

    </div>
<% end %>

<%= field_set_tag "Field Set B" do %>
    <div>

        <%= f.label :"Configure B" %>
        <%= f.check_box :ConfigB %>
        <%= f.label :"Login" %>
        <%= f.text_field :B_Login, {:size => 12} %>
        <%= f.label :"Password" %>
        <%= f.password_field :B_Password, {:size => 12} %>

        <!-- more Ruby code here -->

    </div>
<% end %>

<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
</div>

<!-- more field_sets and Ruby code here -->

<% end %>
```

I also tried this with no luck either

```
<input type="submit" value="Update" />
```

Comment: Could you please also provide the HTML that is rendered for this form? Also, what exactly dows Firefox do when you press the submit button? Just nothing, no submit, no error message?

Comment: When I click the button, it highlights but does nothing, no error message, no page change, nothing. The html that is rendered is the following
    <div class="actions">
        <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Update" />
    </div>

Comment: No, the preceding 2 lines are </div> and </fieldset> and the subsequent line is </form> which is the closing of the entire form and that's it.

Comment: Would you now pretty please post the opening form tag?

Comment: here it is
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/my_tests/4" class="edit_my_test" id="l2c_test" method="post" name="L2C Test"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="Qp2rwc9Of8Bc535dNmTPW4eu6Otd9ZgfDEeW50mKnnI=" /></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was caused by a button I configured as a place holder for future use like this

```
<div class="field">
    <%= button_to "Advanced" %>
</div>
```

When I removed that button, all worked fine

In a similar way, I configured 2 successive submit buttons like this

```
<div class="actions">
    <%= button_to "Update", :type => "submit" %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <%= button_to "Update", :type => "submit" %>
</div>
```

the 1st one does submit but the 2nd one generates this error

```
Unknown action

The action '4' could not be found for L2CircuitTestsController
```

2 or more successive "Advanced" buttons cause the same behavior : only the 1st one does the job and the other are eclipsed!